# Prove that $\cos A + \cos B + \cos C \geq \frac{1}{4}(3 + \cos(A - B) + \cos(B - C) + \cos(C - A))$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have simplified the inequality as these but, can't proceed further:
$$3(\cos A + \cos B + \cos C) \geq 3 + 2(\cos A\cos B + \cos B\cos C + \cos C\cos A)$$
$$(2\cos A-1)(\cos B-1)+(2\cos B-1)(\cos C-1)+(2\cos C-1)(\cos A-1) \leq 0$$

Comment: $$A+B+C=\pi$$ ?

Comment: This is certainly not true for $$A=B=C={\pi \over 2}$$ Some additional constraint must be supplied. Are A,B,C angles of a triangle? For example, the inequality holds for $$A=B=C={\pi \over 3}$$